# Having trouble getting rateLimit working in Argo Events sensor trigger

Tags: kubernetes, events, rate-limiting, argo-events

I'm trying to limit the number of Argo workflows started per minute in an Argo events sensor trigger using the rateLimit parameter as specified in https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/sensors/more-about-sensors-and-triggers/.  But no luck so far.

Here's a snippet of my sensor YAML test script:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: amqp-level0
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: test-dep
      eventSourceName: amqp-interval
      eventName: interval
  triggers:
    - rateLimit:
        unit: Minute
        requestsPerUnit: 5
    - template:
        name: amqp-workflow-trigger
        k8s:
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              ...
```

Without the rateLimit block, the sensor loads into k8s fine.  But with that block, it doesn't run, and I see the following in the controller-manager logs:

```
{"level":"error","ts":1680700596.098304,"logger":"argo-events.eventbus-controller","caller":"sensor/controller.go:74","msg":"reconcile error","namespace":"argo-events","sensor":"amqp-level0","error":"trigger template can't be nil","stacktrace":"github.com/argoproj/argo-events/controllers/sensor.(*reconciler).Reconcile\n\t/home/runner/work/argo-events/argo-events/controllers/sensor/controller.go:74\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Reconcile\n\t/home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.11.2/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:114\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\t/home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.11.2/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:311\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\t/home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.11.2/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:266\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2\n\t/home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.11.2/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:227"}
```

(Note the "trigger template can't be nil", which seems to be the issue, but I haven't figured out how to resolve.)

The Argo events installed is 1.7.6, and Argo is

```
> argo version
argo: v3.4.6
  BuildDate: 2023-03-31T19:53:49Z
  GitCommit: 988706dd131cf98808f09fb7cc03780e2af94c73
  GitTreeState: clean
  GitTag: v3.4.6
  GoVersion: go1.18.10
  Compiler: gc
  Platform: linux/amd64
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got back to this and figured out the proper nomenclature.  The rateLimit block needs to be entered with (or at least works with) the following syntax:

```
triggers:
  - template:
      name: amqp-workflow-trigger
      k8s:
        operation: create
        source:
          ...

    rateLimit:
      unit: Minutes
      requestsPerUnit: 5
```

With that, the sensor is reading event messages at the prescribed rate.